# Disable network encyption MySQL

Tags: mysql, c, networking, encryption

I'd like to look at the network packets going between the client application I'm writing and my MySQL 8.0 server. I have followed the instructions here:

https://scalegrid.io/blog/configuring-and-managing-ssl-on-your-mysql-server/

i.e, moved the *.pem files to a backup folder and added "ssl=0" to the **auto.cnf** file (there is no **my.cnf** file) and rebooted, but when I connect to the server with:

```
mysql_real_connect(pMySQL, pMySQLHostName, "<user>", "<password>", "", 0, NULL, SSL_MODE_DISABLED)
```

and then check with:

```
mysql_get_ssl_cipher(pMySQL)
```

I get the following:

ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256

and when I look in the MySQL server directory I see that some ***.pem** files have "magically" reappeared.

How do I disable encryption so I can see what packets are being sent in plain text?